# Source data type "200" not found error when exporting query results to excel Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am very new to Microsoft SQL Server and am using 2012 Management Studio. I get the error above when I try to export query results to an excel file using the wizard. I have seen solutions posted elsewhere for this error but do not know enough to figure out how to implement the solutions recommended. Can somebody please walk me through one of these solutions step by step?

I believe my problem is that the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Does Not Recognise Varchar and NVarchar which I believe is the data type for the columns that I am receiving errors for.

[Source Type 200 in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823628/source-type-200-in-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/775897/sql-server-import-and-export-wizard-does-not-recognise-varchar-and-nvarchar#

Query:

```
SELECT     licenseEntitlement.entID, licenseEntitlement.entStartDate, entEndDate, quote.quoteId, quote.accountId, quote.clientId, quote.clientName, quote.contactName, 
                      quote.contactEmail, quote.extReference, quote.purchaseOrderNumber, quote.linkedTicket
FROM         licenseEntitlement INNER JOIN
                      quote ON quote.quoteId = SUBSTRING(licenseEntitlement.entComments, 12, PATINDEX('% Created%', licenseEntitlement.entComments) - 12)
inner join sophos521.dbo.computersanddeletedcomputers on computersanddeletedcomputers.name = entid and IsNumeric(computersanddeletedcomputers.name) = 1
WHERE     (licenseEntitlement.entType = 'AVS') AND (licenseEntitlement.entComments LIKE 'OV Order + %') and entenddate < '4/1/2014' 
ORDER BY licenseEntitlement.entEndDate
```

Error:

```
TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

Column information for the source and the destination data could not be retrieved, or the data types of source columns were not mapped correctly to those available on the destination provider.


[Query] -> `Query`:

          - Column "accountId": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "clientId": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "clientName": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "contactName": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "contactEmail": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "extReference": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "purchaseOrderNumber": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
          - Column "linkedTicket": Source data type "200" was not found in the data type mapping file.
```

If any more details are needed please let me know

Comment: I think you need to show the query you ran, describe the data types of the columns returned, describe the steps you took to export the results and the error you got. No-one here is going to do what you want - if I can't answer in 5 minutes I probably won't unless I'm personally interested - none of us get paid for this and your question asks for an amount of effort with no clear limit.

Comment: The SSIS tag has been added:  the export data wizard, in Mgmt Studio, is running `SSIS` (SQL Server Integration Studio), so this is an SSIS error.  Simon is right, though:  we need more detail.  I suggest starting with giving us the *full & exact text* of the error message.  And, since `data type` is a property of a column, tell us what you can about the columns.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I added details. I thought there might be an easy work-around that could be explained in simple terms that weren't too technical due to my limited knowledge here. If that is not the case just let me know and I can remove the question. Thanks again.

Comment: First, this is acknowledged by Microsoft as a known bug in the import/export wizard.  Secondly, the recommended workaround in all of the links is to turn your query into a View, and then export from *that*.  Why can't you implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, implementing the suggestion at the StackOverflow link you gave, of turning the query into a `View`, here's an example of what that could look like (with some code formatting ;) --

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test__View_1]
AS
SELECT LIC.entID, LIC.entStartDate, entEndDate, 
    quote.quoteId, quote.accountId, quote.clientId, quote.clientName, 
    quote.contactName, quote.contactEmail, quote.extReference, 
    quote.purchaseOrderNumber, quote.linkedTicket
FROM [dbo].licenseEntitlement  LIC  WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].quote  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON quote.quoteId = SUBSTRING(LIC.entComments, 12, 
            PATINDEX('% Created%', LIC.entComments) - 12)
    INNER JOIN sophos521.dbo.computersanddeletedcomputers  COMPS  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON COMPS.name = entid and IsNumeric(COMPS.name) = 1
WHERE (LIC.entType = 'AVS') 
  AND (LIC.entComments LIKE 'OV Order + %') 
  and (entenddate < '4/1/2014')
ORDER BY LIC.entEndDate

GO
```

Then, you would export from `test__View_1` (or whatever real name you choose for it), as if `test__View_1` was the table name.

FYI, after the ***first time*** you've executed the above -- after you've "created" the view -- then from then on, the view's first line (during modifications) changes, from `CREATE VIEW`, to `ALTER VIEW`.

((And, aside from the bug question... in your `WHERE` clause, did you intend `entComments LIKE 'OV Order + %'`, or was that really intended to be `entComments LIKE 'OV Order%'`?  I've made that change, in the alternative example code, below.))

Note:  if you're going to be exporting *repeatedly* (or re-using) the output from one run, and especially if your query is slow or hogs the machine... then instead of a `VIEW`, you might prefer a `SELECT INTO`, to create a table ***once***, which can be quickly re-used.  (I would also choose `SELECT INTO` rather than `CREATE VIEW`, when developing a one-time-only query for export.)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'zz_LIC_ENT_DETAIL')
    DROP TABLE [dbo].zz_LIC_ENT_DETAIL

SELECT LIC.entID, LIC.entStartDate, LIC.entEndDate, 
    quote.quoteId, quote.accountId, quote.clientId, quote.clientName, 
    quote.contactName, quote.contactEmail, quote.extReference, 
    quote.purchaseOrderNumber, quote.linkedTicket
INTO [dbo].zz_LIC_ENT_DETAIL
FROM [dbo].licenseEntitlement  LIC  WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].quote  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON quote.quoteId = SUBSTRING(LIC.entComments, 12, 
            PATINDEX('% Created%', LIC.entComments) - 12)
    INNER JOIN sophos521.dbo.computersanddeletedcomputers  COMPS  WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON COMPS.name = LIC.entid and IsNumeric(COMPS.name) = 1
WHERE (LIC.entType = 'AVS') 
  AND (LIC.entComments LIKE 'OV Order%') 
  and (LIC.entenddate < '4/1/2014')
ORDER BY LIC.entEndDate
```

Then, you would of course export from table `zz_LIC_ENT_DETAIL` (or whatever table name you chose).

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to right click query results window and choosing Save Results As (CSV)..

To append the column names in the first row you'd also need to modify your query in this way (note the cast for int or datetime columns):

```
select 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'
union all
select cast(id as varchar(10)), name, cast(someinfo as varchar(28))
from Question1355876
```

Comment: Note: if you are working working with millions of rows this will not work