# Review Data Type Mapping Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, dts

Please see the DDL below:

```
 create table test (id int identity not null, field1 varchar(30),
field2 nvarchar(30), dateadded datetime, primary key (id))

insert into test (field1,field2,dateadded) values ('Test1', 'Test2','2016-01-01')
insert into test (field1,field2,dateadded) values ('Test3', 'Test4', '2015-01-01')
insert into test (field1,field2,dateadded) values ('Test5', 'Test6','2014-01-01')
```

The 'test' table is created on [Server 1].Database1.

I want to transfer the data to [server 2].database2 (only a subset of the records) using DTS.  I specify [Server1].database1 as the source and [server 2].database2 as the destination.  I specify a source query of: select * from test where dateadded >= '2016-01-01'

However, I am then asked to review data type mapping issues.  I am not sure how to resolve this in the source query.  How do I resolve it?

Here is some information about source server 1 (version and collation):

```
 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64) 
        Sep 21 2011 22:45:45 
        Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (VM) 
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

here is some information about the destination server 2 (version and collation):

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) 
    Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

If I use a source table rather than a source query then it works.  However, the source table contains 80 million records and I only require about 10,000 of then, which is why I am using a source query rather than a source table.

The error is: "Found 2 unknown column type conversion(s).  You are only allowed to save the package"

How do I resolve the data type mapping issues in the source query? I have tried this:

```
select field1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,field2 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,dateadded from test
```

Comment: You are using `DTS`, not `SSIS`? And what particular issue are you facing? Is there some error message, some form of problem when transferring the data?

Comment: @TT, I have updated the question.  The error is: "Found 2 unknown column type conversion(s).  You are only allowed to save the package".  The DTS package does not run.

Comment: @TT, it appears that it may be a bug in SQL Server 2012 as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823628/source-type-200-in-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Comment: I assume you plan to update to `SQL Server 2012 SP2` to try and fix this issue?

Comment: @TT, yes that is what I will have to do according to one of the answers in the question I have linked to.